# Global access instead of localhost use

Tags: joomla, hosting

I am new in web design.

I am trying to make my own website using Joomla.

When I want to see the output of my work I use localhost.

However I want to make my site publically available in order to have access from different devices to test it.

How can I do this?

Using a domain and somewhere to host the page? In order to host the site I need a server? How can I make it to my PC?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

Most hosting companies design their sites for people without server knowledge to easily buy a domain and server space - usually you just have to fill in a form.  It might be worth emailing them first to make sure they can handle Joomla (most should be able to).

Requirements - http://www.joomla.org/technical-requirements.html

When you have a host, Akeeba Backup and Akeeba Kickstart can make copying the site to the new server easier.

Bear in mind also that a live site can be accessed by nefarious people too - so keeping backups (again, Akeeba Backup makes this simple) and patching Joomla (JUpgrade) is important to protect your site from hackers when it is live.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need a domain name.
2. You can either use a webhost (there are lots of good ones) or host the server on your computer.

If you host it yourself the server (computer) always has to be on. You don't have to worry about that for hosting it elsewhere. So as a beginner I would suggest a webhost. Most have support for Joomla anyway or can be easily added.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Are they free? Any example?

Comment: Depends on the host. Some free ones include 000webhost.com and zymic.com. I use heliohost.org which is alright also. Paid ones usually have more/better features. I would suggest 1&1 for paid hosting.

Comment: I host my server on my computer, and I use http://www.dot.tk/ for all my DNS mumbo-jumbo.

Comment: Yeah dot.tk is great for your domain.

Comment: Any example how I can make it to my own computer?

Comment: Try looking at this [tutorial](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=RZTYqTGqtjI). It's a decent explanation for hosting it. Basically you have to point the domain name to your ip and do a few other things.

Comment: There is web servers like [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/) and also [Nginx](http://nginx.org/).  I use Apache personally, so I'm not sure about Nginx

Comment: Not sure dot.tk is a great domain.  Yes, they are free, but that means they are commonly used as spam.  If SEO is important, then get a domain that matches your location or what the site is about.  They aren't that expensive.